# merging tables into one data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have several columns in my source data frame containing the same three possible variables (1, 2 and 3) over several hundred rows. I'm using the table function to summarize each column as shown here

```
column1 <- table(data$column1)
column2 <- table(data$column2)
column3 <- table(data$column3)
...
```

These tables print out results of the form below

```
1 2 3
6 74 300
```

I'm trying to combine all of these tables into one data frame of this form

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| column1 | 6 | 74 | 300 |
| column2 | 2 | 87 | 298 |
| column3 | 4 | 57 | 489 |

How do I make this happen? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution using rbind from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/RStudio/comments/kt7iej/merging_tables_into_one_data_frame/). It does exactly what I was looking for.

```
#selected all tables in the environment
 tables = sapply(.GlobalEnv, is.table)
#rbinded them
 allquestions <- do.call(rbind, mget(names(tables)[tables]))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `tidyverse`, suppose your data is called `dat`:

```
library(tidyverse) 
dat %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    count(name, value) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n)

#   name       `1`   `2`    `3`
# 1 column1     6    74    300
# 2 column2     2    87    298
# 3 column3     4    57    489
```

Comment: Thank you! But it seems this gets me to this error 

`Error in UseMethod("pivot_longer") : 
  no applicable method for 'pivot_longer' applied to an object of class "function"`

Comment: what is the name of the data.frame your data is stored in?

Comment: my initial data is stored in a dataframe called "data"

Comment: `data` is a reserved name for [a function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/data) that already exists in R. I would encourage you to not use it as a variable name